# PHP inline access to Array elements returned by an Object Method

Tags: php, arrays

Say we have the object `$teams` (an associative array) containing an object that provides the method `getMembers()` which returns an Array as follows:

```
$membersArray = $teams['blueteam']->getMembers();
```

If I want to then access individual members, I may do so as follows:

```
$membersArray[1];
```

Why can't I perform the access in-line as follows, and is there a proper way to do so in PHP?

```
$membersArray = $teams['blueteam']->getMembers()[1];
```

Comment: You can in PHP 5.4.0 and higher.

Comment: Refer to [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#example-88).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Support for this added in PHP 5.4.0:

```
$membersArray = $teams['blueteam']->getMembers()[1];
```

Comment: Ah! Well, I'm using 5.36 and can't move to 5.4 in my case. I will live I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than try to access it like that, why not make an alternative method called `getMember()` which accepts a parameter for the array index. For example:

```
function getMember( $index )
{
    return $this->members[$index];
}
```

This makes your code a little more *self-documenting* by indicating `getMembers` will return an array of members, where `getMember()` will only return a single array element.

Comment: This is an excellent suggestion, and I have already done so, but I encounter this situation all the time and am not satisfied.

Comment: @ktamlyn you could use `getMembers($index = null)` and if its not `null` return an individual row.